# rotate gif image to right when hover on it using css3 and html5

Tags: html, css, rotation, gif

How can I rotate gif image when mouse hover on it using css3

```
#tiger:hover{
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg)
}
```

Comment: when i use transform: rotate(-90deg) it doesnot make the tigger look to right , it make the tigger to look to the bottom

Comment: Then you post the _tiger_ so we can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transform: rotate(90deg)`

```css
img:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/150/f00" alt="image">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```css
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;

}
.image:hover{
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
<img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```